# How to show a different navbar in react router depending on the user authentication?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-router-dom

I need to render a different navbar depending on the users authentication. There is a global navbar but for Vault component in below, I want to render a different navbar. How can I implement a different navbar assuming that user is authenticated?

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Navbar />
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' component={Landing} exact />
                <Route path='/login' component={Login} exact />
                <Route path='/registration' component={Registration} exact />
                <Route path='/authtest' component={AuthTest} exact />
                <Route path='/home' component={Home} exact />
                <Route path='/search' component={search} exact />
                <Route path='/profile' component={Visualize} exact />
                <Route path='/vault' component={Vault} exact />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it simply by using ternary

```
const[isLogin,setIsLogin]=useState(true);

 <Switch>
  {isLogin?<Route path="/" >
    <Header1/>
    </Route>
    : 
    <Route path="/" >
    <Header2/>
    </Route>}
  </Switch>
```

isLogin is a state which will keep track whether user is loggedin or not if user logged in render Header1 &  if user is not logged in render Header2